# Java - Easiest way to find shortest path between two nodes

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, shortest-path

[image]I am creating a network/graph of all the cities and the their neighbors in the picture above.

I am attempting to create a method which will find the shortest path from one node another. There is no weight on the edges. For example, If I am attempting to find the shortest path between "Los Angeles" and "Montreal", I should see the following result:

```
> (find-shortest-path "los angeles" "montreal" ticket-to-ride)
 "los angeles"
 "san francisco"
 "salt lake city"
 "helena"
 "winnipeg"
 "sault ste. marie"
```

I have created a program called shortest_path so far, which is able to find the "start" parameter in my graph, and the "end" parameter, only if it is one of its neighbors. How can I look through each neighboring city and find the shortest path between the two nodes? Is it possible to create an array of LinkedLists which contain all the paths between the "start" and the "end", in order to return the shortest? What would be the best strategy in order to accomplish this? Here is the program I have created starting with the city, neighbor, and graph classes:

City Class:

```
import java.util.*;  
public class city{
  String city;
  boolean visited;

  public city(String s){
    this.city = s;
    visited = false;
  }
  public String toString() {
    return this.city; 
  }
  public void setVisited(boolean b){
    this.visited = b;
  }
}
```

Neighbor class:

```
import java.util.*;  
public class neighbors extends ArrayList<city> {
  public neighbors (city[] n) {
    for (city v : n)
      this.add(v); 
  }
  public ArrayList<city> toArrayList() {
    return this; 
  }
}
```

Main method is in this class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class shortest_path{


  public static void find_shortest_path(String start, String end, Graph graph){



    city best;
    city current;

    neighbors n;
    Iterator<Map.Entry<city, neighbors>> it = graph.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<city, neighbors> pair = it.next();
        if(pair.getKey().toString() == start){
          //best = pair;
          best = pair.getKey();
          best.setVisited(true);

          System.out.println("Start : " + best.toString()); //THE START IS FOUND
          //Iterate through the neighbors from the start
          for (city c: best.getValue())
          {
            while(!(c.visited == true))
            {
              c.setVisited(true);
              if (!(c.toString() == end))
              {
                temp.setVisited(true);
                System.out.println("End : " + c.toString()); //THE END
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){

    Graph a = new Graph(); 

    city vancouver = new city("vancouver");
    city calgary = new city("calgary");
    city winnipeg = new city("winnipeg");
    city sault_ste_marie = new city("sault ste. marie");
    city montreal = new city("montreal");
    city boston = new city("boston");
    city new_york = new city("new york");
    city toronto = new city("toronto");
    city pittsburgh = new city("pittsburgh");
    city washington = new city("washington");
    city raleigh = new city("raleigh");
    city charleston = new city("charleston");
    city miami = new city("miami");
    city atlanta = new city("atlanta");
    city nashville = new city("nashville");
    city chicago = new city("chicago");
    city saint_louis = new city("saint louis");
    city little_rock = new city("little rock");
    city new_orleans = new city("new_orleans");
    city houston = new city("houston");
    city dallas = new city("dallas");
    city oklahoma_city = new city("oklahoma city");
    city kansas_city = new city("kansas city");
    city omaha = new city("omaha");
    city duluth = new city("duluth");
    city helena = new city("helena");
    city salt_lake_city = new city("salt lake city");
    city denver = new city("denver");
    city santa_fe = new city("santa fe");
    city el_paso = new city("el paso");
    city phoenix = new city("phoenix");
    city las_vegas = new city("las vegas");
    city san_francisco = new city("san francisco");
    city los_angeles = new city("los angeles");
    city portland = new city("portland");
    city seattle = new city("seattle");

    a.put(vancouver, new neighbors( new city[] { calgary, seattle } )); 
    a.put(calgary, new neighbors( new city[] { vancouver, seattle, helena, winnipeg } )); 
    a.put(winnipeg, new neighbors( new city[] { calgary, helena, duluth, sault_ste_marie } )); 
    a.put(sault_ste_marie, new neighbors( new city[] { winnipeg, duluth, toronto, montreal } ));
    a.put(montreal, new neighbors( new city[] { boston, new_york, toronto, sault_ste_marie } ));
    a.put(boston, new neighbors( new city[] { montreal, new_york } ));
    a.put(new_york, new neighbors( new city[] { washington, pittsburgh, montreal, boston } ));
    a.put(toronto, new neighbors( new city[] { sault_ste_marie, montreal, pittsburgh, duluth, chicago } ));
    a.put(pittsburgh, new neighbors( new city[] { toronto, new_york, washington, raleigh, nashville, saint_louis, chicago } ));
    a.put(washington, new neighbors( new city[] { new_york, pittsburgh, raleigh } ));
    a.put(raleigh, new neighbors( new city[] { charleston, atlanta, nashville, pittsburgh, washington } ));
    a.put(charleston, new neighbors( new city[] { raleigh, atlanta, miami } ));
    a.put(miami, new neighbors( new city[] { charleston, atlanta, new_orleans } ));
    a.put(atlanta, new neighbors( new city[] { raleigh, charleston, miami, new_orleans, nashville } ));
    a.put(nashville, new neighbors( new city[] { saint_louis, little_rock, atlanta, raleigh, pittsburgh } ));
    a.put(chicago, new neighbors( new city[] { pittsburgh, saint_louis, toronto, duluth, omaha } ));
    a.put(saint_louis, new neighbors( new city[] { chicago, pittsburgh, nashville, little_rock, kansas_city } ));
    a.put(little_rock, new neighbors( new city[] { nashville, new_orleans, dallas, oklahoma_city, saint_louis } ));
    a.put(new_orleans, new neighbors( new city[] { houston, little_rock, atlanta, miami } ));
    a.put(houston, new neighbors( new city[] { el_paso, dallas, new_orleans } ));
    a.put(dallas, new neighbors( new city[] { little_rock, houston, el_paso, oklahoma_city } ));
    a.put(oklahoma_city, new neighbors( new city[] { denver, kansas_city, little_rock, dallas, el_paso, santa_fe } ));
    a.put(kansas_city, new neighbors( new city[] { omaha, saint_louis, oklahoma_city, denver } ));
    a.put(omaha, new neighbors( new city[] { helena, duluth, chicago, kansas_city, denver } ));
    a.put(duluth, new neighbors( new city[] { winnipeg, sault_ste_marie, toronto, chicago, omaha, helena } ));
    a.put(helena, new neighbors( new city[] { seattle, calgary, winnipeg, duluth, omaha, denver, salt_lake_city } ));
    a.put(salt_lake_city, new neighbors( new city[] { portland, helena, denver, las_vegas, san_francisco } ));
    a.put(denver, new neighbors( new city[] { salt_lake_city, helena, omaha, kansas_city, oklahoma_city, santa_fe, phoenix } ));
    a.put(santa_fe, new neighbors( new city[] { denver, oklahoma_city, el_paso, phoenix } ));
    a.put(el_paso, new neighbors( new city[] { los_angeles, phoenix, santa_fe, oklahoma_city, dallas, houston } ));
    a.put(phoenix, new neighbors( new city[] { los_angeles, denver, santa_fe, el_paso } ));
    a.put(las_vegas, new neighbors( new city[] { salt_lake_city, los_angeles } ));
    a.put(san_francisco, new neighbors( new city[] { portland, salt_lake_city, los_angeles } ));
    a.put(los_angeles, new neighbors( new city[] { san_francisco, las_vegas, phoenix, el_paso } ));
    a.put(portland, new neighbors( new city[] { seattle, salt_lake_city, san_francisco } ));
    a.put(seattle, new neighbors( new city[] { vancouver, calgary, helena, portland } ));

    find_shortest_path("omaha", "helena", a); // should work easily
    //find_shortest_path("omaha", "toronto", a); // should be difficult
  }
}
```

What would be the easiest way to accomplish this task? Any tips or modifications will be helpful.

Comment: So, you basically have a "travelling salesman" problem, I'd highly recommend looking to that

Comment: It's a beautiful excercise to improve your coding skills, but in this form not really a SO question. There are many examples online to go through interconnected nodes. If you have a specific problem, you can ask it here.

Comment: @MadProgrammer More like an all-pair-shortest-path problem? [Floyd-Warshall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd–Warshall_algorithm)

Comment: @xiaofeng.li Possibly, it just jumps out at me as TS issue because that's what I know ;)